# How can i create a secondary index using HBase Shell?

Tags: performance, indexing, filter, hbase

I am trying to create a faster way to scan and filter my tables with HBASE. I decided trying some kind of secondary indexing but i am not using Phoenix. The question is, is it possible to create it using solely hbase shell?

if yes, how can i do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Starting with https://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html what is your question?

Comment: I wanna know if there is a way to create a secondary index with hbase shell. I am not so experienced with hbase and stuff.

I tried something like:
`CREATE INDEX index-name ON my_trable_name(index_column)`

The problem is that i dont know if i can do something like that in hbase shell

Comment: The link I mention seems to indicate no.